# Logging with the elk stack

Tags: elk

Can I send logs from my filebeat hosted on minikube to my elasticsearch and kibana hosted on docker?

I do not know how to go about it?
Below is the yaml file of my filebeats:

---

### apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
name: filebeat
namespace: kube-system
labels:
k8s-app: filebeat

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
name: filebeat
labels:
k8s-app: filebeat
rules:

- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:

  - namespaces
  - pods
  - nodes
    verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources:

  - replicasets
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:

  - jobs
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
name: filebeat

## should be the namespace where filebeat is running

namespace: kube-system
labels:
k8s-app: filebeat
rules:

- apiGroups:

  - coordination.k8s.io
    resources:
  - leases
    verbs: ["get", "create", "update"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
namespace: kube-system
labels:
k8s-app: filebeat
rules:

- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:

  - configmaps
    resourceNames:
  - kubeadm-config
    verbs: ["get"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
name: filebeat
subjects:

- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
name: filebeat
namespace: kube-system
subjects:

- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
namespace: kube-system
subjects:

- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: filebeat-kubeadm-config
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: filebeat-config
namespace: kube-system
labels:
k8s-app: filebeat
data:
filebeat.yml: |-
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
paths:
- /var/log/containers/*.log
processors:
- add_kubernetes_metadata:
host: ${NODE_NAME}
matchers:
- logs_path:
logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

```
# To enable hints based autodiscover, remove `filebeat.inputs` configuration and uncomment this:
#filebeat.autodiscover:
#  providers:
#    - type: kubernetes
#      node: ${NODE_NAME}
#      hints.enabled: true
#      hints.default_config:
#        type: container
#        paths:
#          - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log

processors:
  - add_cloud_metadata:
  - add_host_metadata:

cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
  username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
  password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
```

---

### apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
name: filebeat
namespace: kube-system
labels:
k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
k8s-app: filebeat
template:
metadata:
labels:
k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
serviceAccountName: filebeat
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
hostNetwork: true
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
containers:
- name: filebeat
image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.9.2
args: [
"-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
"-e",
]
env:
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
value: elasticsearch
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
value: "9200"
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
value: elastic
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
value: 4-oG5V6YX4QYUB*HwUMJ
- name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
value:
- name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
value:
- name: NODE_NAME
valueFrom:
fieldRef:
fieldPath: spec.nodeName
securityContext:
runAsUser: 0
# If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
#privileged: true
resources:
limits:
memory: 200Mi
requests:
cpu: 100m
memory: 100Mi
volumeMounts:
- name: config
mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
readOnly: true
subPath: filebeat.yml
- name: data
mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
- name: varlibdockercontainers
mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
readOnly: true
- name: varlog
mountPath: /var/log
readOnly: true
volumes:
- name: config
configMap:
defaultMode: 0640
name: filebeat-config
- name: varlibdockercontainers
hostPath:
path: /var/lib/docker/containers
- name: varlog
hostPath:
path: /var/log
# data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
- name: data
hostPath:
# When filebeat runs as non-root user, this directory needs to be writable by group (g+w).
path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
type: DirectoryOrCreate